# Is there a way to fix my program as it is not adding properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I wrote this code just today so there may be many bugs. The numbers being processed in the second function of class nums are not adding properly. I do not know why. For further information, I use python IDLE version 3.8. Please do not hand out the answer and explain to me why this is not working. I assume it is something to do with using the .value too much or inappropriately. 
Example Image:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXyre.png
New Image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ayjqw.png
Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
#number assignments
class nums:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value=randint(1,100)
    def assignnewnums(master,oldnum1,oldnum2,lbltxt,lbl,answer):
        getans = answer.get()
        if(int(getans)==(oldnum1.value+oldnum2.value)):
           oldnum1=nums()
           oldnum2=nums()
           display = Label(master,text="Correct",bg="black",fg="red").pack(side=RIGHT)
           lbltxt="What is {} + {}".format(oldnum1.value,oldnum2.value)
           lbl.config(text=lbltxt)
        else:
            display = Label(master,text="Incorrect",bg="black",fg="red").pack(side=RIGHT)
            lbltxt="What is {} + {}".format(oldnum1.value,oldnum2.value)
            lbl.config(text=lbltxt)
a = nums()
b = nums()
#GUI startup
root = Tk()
#Label
title = Label(root, text="AddPrac", fg="dark blue")
title.pack()
#Question
questxt = "What is {} + {}".format(a.value,b.value)
ques = Label(root,text=questxt,fg="red")
ques.pack()
#UserAnswer
ans = Entry(root)
ans.pack()
#SubmitButton
enter = Button(root,text="Submit Answer!",fg="yellow",command=lambda: nums.assignnewnums(root,a,b,questxt,ques,ans))
enter.pack()
#GUI continued startup
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: simply use `print()` to see values in variables - it can help to see problem.

Comment: Are you having this problem on the first time answering? Or just on second, third, fourth try? Because it looks like a and b aren't being updated

Comment: This a largely useless `class` which is making this much harder.

Comment: https://www.programmingtalks.org/talk/stop-writing-classes

Comment: @schwartz721 this happens not on the first try but on usually the second, fourth, and the even numbers after it.

Comment: @StephenRauch I was trying to use a class as practice because I have just learned about them. Thank you for the link though as it will help me understand their importance.

Comment: your class is very strange. I wouldn't put `assignnewnums` in class because it has nothing to do with `self.value` - it always uses other values (from other instances).

Comment: problem is that after answer you create new `oldnum1=nums()` and `oldnum1 = nums()` but button always use the same `a`,`b` which have only old values.

Comment: BTW: as I said at start - if you would use `print()` to see values in variables then you would see this problem long time ago.

Comment: @furas Ok, but I do not understand why this(the function) does not work.

Comment: I have added a new picture. In the image, I have been spamming 132. Using furas's idea, the printed answers are in the shell as shown in blue text to the right of the screen. The printed answers are different than the ones I have been inputting but are still shown to be correct.

Comment: when you press button then it always gets values from original `a`, `b` which always have the same values - generated at start. But after first question you create `oldnum1=nums()` to generate and display new values in label - but it doesn't change values in `a`, `b` which are used again when you press button - `command=lambda: nums.assignnewnums(...,a,b,...)`

Comment: Asterisk imports are discouraged, be careful. Why are you using a class here?

Comment: Why did you delete your most recent post about this program?

Comment: This is because you said that I needed to rework it. Thus, the post no longer serves a purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a and b and never update them. In python, arguments are passed by assignment. Some data types are mutable, and others aren't. If the argument that's passed in is mutable, then the method gets a **reference** to the object.

With the reference, the method can change the attribute of the nums object (i.e. oldnum1.value and oldnum2.value). However, if the reference is ever rebound to something else (i.e. oldnum1 = nums() and oldnum2), the outer scope will not know about this change and the outer reference will still point to the old values (a and b) after the function finishes.

Instead of rebinding the whole nums objects here

```
oldnum1=nums()
oldnum2=nums()
```

you can change the value attributes of these objects.

```
oldnum1.value = randint(1,100)
oldnum2.value = randint(1,100)
```

This will mutate a and b by reference instead of rebinding the reference and losing it within the assignnewnums method.

Answer (score 1):

a and b aren't being updated. Your function updates the Label with new values for oldnum1 and oldnum2, but your submit button takes a and b as arguments. I bet if you submit the same answer the second and third time as you do the first time, it will say you are correct.

Update:

The class definitely overcomplicates things here, but experimenting it good. Here's an example of your class that works:

```
class nums:
    def __init__(self):
        self.assignnewnums()
    def check(master,oldnum1,oldnum2,lbltxt,lbl,answer):
        getans = answer.get()
        if(int(getans)==(oldnum1.value+oldnum2.value)):
           oldnum1.assignnewnums()
           oldnum2.assignnewnums()
           display = Label(master,text="Correct",bg="black",fg="red").pack(side=RIGHT)
           lbltxt="What is {} + {}".format(oldnum1.value,oldnum2.value)
           lbl.config(text=lbltxt)
        else:
            display = Label(master,text="Incorrect",bg="black",fg="red").pack(side=RIGHT)
            lbltxt="What is {} + {}".format(oldnum1.value,oldnum2.value)
            lbl.config(text=lbltxt)
    def assignnewnums(self):
        self.value=randint(1,100)
```

assignnewnums now changes the value attribute of the nums object. You'll notice that instead of creating new nums objects in the check function, we use assignnewnums to keep those objects, but just give them new values.

Make sure you change the Button command to nums.check(args) instead of nums.assignnewnums(args)

Comment: In the function attached to the submit button, you pass in a and b. In your function, a and b are given the names oldnum1 and oldnum2, and then compared to the answer you submitted. Then you change oldnum1 and oldnum2, but a and b stay the same. The next time you press submit, you are again comparing your answer against the sum of a and b (which haven't changed).

Comment: Thank you so much! Are there any practices you would recommend me to practice so that I do not overlook such mistakes later on.

Comment: Also, how would I update the sum of a and b at the same time the oldnums are updated.